# Did King Josiah engage in Human Sacrifice? (2 Kings 23)

Tags: sacrifice, josiah

> "The altar which was at Bethel, the high place built by Jeroboam, son
> of Nebat, who caused Israel to sin—this same altar and high place he
> tore down and burned, grinding the high place to powder and burning
> the asherah. 16 When Josiah turned and saw the graves there on the
> mountainside, he ordered the bones taken from the graves and burned on
> the altar..." (2 Kings 23)

The narrator seems to approve of this action, but it strikes me that digging up graves and burning them on an altar is a form of human sacrifice--not in the sense of taking a human life to offer it to a deity, but in the sense of using human bodies in a kind of reverse-offering, to defile an unauthorized altar.

So: did Josiah conduct a type of human sacrifice? Is there a biblical justification for digging up dead bodies and burning them on an Israelite altar?

Comment: *"The narrator seems to approve"* - where?

Comment: I mean, in the context of the introduction in ch. 22: "He did what was right in the Lord’s sight, walking in the way of David his father, not turning right or left." And the conclusion in ch. 23: "Before him there had been no king who turned to the Lord as he did, with his whole heart, his whole being, and his whole strength, in accord with the entire law of Moses; nor did any king like him arise after him."

Comment: Great - if you could add that to the Question somewhere that would be perfect

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of the OP, Josiah did engage in "a kind of reverse-offering, to defile an unauthorized altar".  But that is not what human sacrifice means that was prohibited in places like, Hosea 13:2, Isa 66:3, etc.  Note the important difference:

1. Human Sacrifice involved slaughtering a human in sacrifice to appease a god
2. Josiah was involved in desecrating the graves of long-buried people buy exhuming and burning their bones.  This was an ancient practice of insulting the memory of one's enemies, or, insulting the principles they stood for; in this case, those who led Israel into the sin of idolatry.  Thus, no killing was involved and no murder and no appeasement of false gods.

Josiah's purpose was apparently to send a clear message that what these long-dead leaders stood for was not worth remembering and so their memory was "erased" by removing their graves.

Note the comments of the Pulpit Commentary:

> Verse 16. - **And as Josiah turned himself, he spied the sepulchers
> that were there in the mount**. The Israelite sepulchers, excavated in
> the reeky sides of hills, are everywhere conspicuous. Those of Bethel
> may have been in the low hill on which the town stands, or in the
> sides of the Wady Suweinit, a little further to the south. His
> accidentally "spying the sepulchers" gave Josiah the thought of
> completing his desecration of Bethel by having bones brought from them
> and burnt upon the altar - whereby he exactly accomplished the old
> prophecy (1 Kings 13:2), which was not at all in his mind. And sent,
> end took the bones out of the sepulchers, and burned them upon the
> altar, and polluted it (see the comment on ver. 14), according to the
> word of the Lord which the men of God proclaimed, who proclaimed these
> words; rather, who prophesied these things. The reference is to 1
> Kings 13:2, and the meaning is, not that Josiah acted as he did in
> order to fulfill the prophecy, but that in thus acting he
> unconsciously fulfilled it. 2 Kings 23:16

Comment: + 1 although it begs the question as to whether unconsciously fulfilling a prophecy would justify a seemingly barbaric practice - not to mention the ritual defilement brought by handling human remains -- allowed in case of honorable burial but not in order to insult long-dead enemies.